# Angular material slide toggle binding on checked not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

It seems to be so easy, but I just cannot get the `checked` binding of the slide toggle to work.

(I'm using angular `9.1` and material `9.2`.)

Here's the html:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="isSlideChecked" (change)="toggleChanges($event)">isSlideChecked: {{isSlideChecked}}</mat-slide-toggle>

<p *ngFor="let e of toggleEvents">{{e}}</p>
```

Here's the TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-component',
  templateUrl: './test-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-component.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  public isSlideChecked: boolean = false;
  public toggleEvents: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleChanges($event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.toggleEvents.push("Toggle Event: " + $event.checked)
  }
}
```

The `change` event is working fine, `$event.checked` is always set correctly. But the `checked` binding just won't work, it's always staying `false`.

Before I give up and use an odinary checkbox, I hoped someone here could help me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property checked of material slide toggle is only for input binding. Because of that any changes to the toggle by clicking will not be output in `[checked]`. You will have to use the `(change)` event to assign the values from the `event.checked`.

`toggleChanges($event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
}`

You can refer the API documentation for more details,
https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api

Answer (score 1):

anohter way using both`[(ngModel)]` and event `change`.
get value by event and set value by `[(ngModel)]`:

component.html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle 
                 formControlName="myName" 
                 (change)="slideToggleChange($event)"
                 [(ngModel)]="checked">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

component.ts

```
slideToggleChange(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.checked = event.source.checked;   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a link to the [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/slide-toggle-binding-problem).

I'm not sure why, but when I removed the `public` from `isSlideChecked`, the binding started to work. I also removed the `public` from the `toggleEvents` array as well. Hope this helps.